# Three column with image with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using a Bootstrap layout that contains two columns. But now I want to have a little image to the right to an input field. The image has to appear next to the input field snippet.

This is my html layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <p>Op deze pagina kun je de mail die aan nieuw personeel wordt verzonden aanpassen naar je eigen smaak. Pas de content aan en bekijk de preview van de mail voor het te verwachten resultaat.<br /><br /></p>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Afzender, heeftSchrijfrechten)

        <div class="property extra-margin">
            <label>Onderwerp</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Onderwerp, heeftSchrijfrechten)
        </div>

        <div class="property extra-margin">
            <label>Titel</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Titel, heeftSchrijfrechten)
        </div>

        <div class="property extra-margin">
            <label>Snippet</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Snippet, heeftSchrijfrechten)
        </div>

        @*<div class="col-sm-5" >
            <img src="~/Images/EmailTemplate_Snippet.png" />
        </div>*@

        @if (Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoIDSpecified)
        {
            <div class="property wide extra-margin">
                <br />
                <label>
                    Kies header logo
                </label>
                <div class="email-logo">
                    <label>
                        <span class="email-logo-image" id="EmailTemplateCursor">
                            <img src='/Beheer/Images/mainlogo_274x122.png' />
                        </span>
                        <span class="email-logo-button">
                            @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "standaard", !Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                            <span>standaard logo</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="email-logo">
                    <label>
                        <span class="email-logo-image" id="EmailTemplateCursor">
                            <img src='/Beheer/Document/Download?documentID=@(Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoID)' />
                        </span>
                        <span class="email-logo-button">
                            @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "klant", Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                            <span>eigen logo</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="property">
            <label>Introductietekst</label>
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.IntroductieTekst, "HtmlEditorEmailTemplate", heeftSchrijfrechten)
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            <br /> <label>Afzendertekst</label>
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AfzenderTekst, "HtmlEditorEmailTemplate", heeftSchrijfrechten)
        </div>

        @if (heeftSchrijfrechten)
        {
            <div class="navigatie alignRight">
                @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Default, ButtonSize.Large, "Herstel standaard mail", id: "herstel-standaard", icon: "glyphicon-refresh")
                @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Primary, ButtonSize.Large, Messages.Global_Action_Opslaan, "opslaan", icon: "glyphicon-floppy-save")
            </div>
        }
    </div>


    <br />
    <div class="col">
        <img src="~/Images/EmailTemplate_Snippet.png" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <div id="email-template-edit" class="panel panel-default basisViewEdit">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-sub">
                Mail Preview
                <a id="previewEmail" href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="preview-container">
            <div id="preview" class="backgroundTemplateStyle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to have a little image next to the snippet input field. I also added an image for clearness.

[image]

I have it now like this:

```
<div class="property extra-margin input-group">
    <label>Snippet</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Snippet, heeftSchrijfrechten)

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text border-0 bg-white" id="snippet">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it looks now like this:
[image]

Comment: Somebody any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add icons next to input fields by using the [Input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/) component of Bootstrap.

By using **Bootstrap 4-beta 3** the murkup is as follows.

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Placeholder" aria-label="Placeholder" aria-describedby="snippet">

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text border-0 bg-white" id="snippet">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The example above incorporates the “info-circle” icon from fontawesome as an illustration. Also, note the `.border-0 .bg-white` utility classes applied on the `<span>` tag to achieve the desired style.

Please note that with the beta 2 css, the markup is slightly different.

With **Bootstrap 3** the markup changes to the below.

```css
// helper styles not present in Bootstrap 3
.rounded-0 {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.border-0 {
    border: 0 !important;
}
.bg-white {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Placeholder" aria-label="Placeholder" aria-describedby="snippet">

    <div class="input-group-addon border-0 bg-white" id="snippet">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you using? Beta 2?

Comment: * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: Ah, that makes a change! Updated my answer with the markup for Bootstrap 3 as well.

Comment: Hi, I also posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027281/show-popover-by-information-icon-with-bootstrap. Maybe you have a idea to fix that? Thank you