# Show popover next to icon with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, popover

I have an information icon from bootstrap:

```
<div class="input-group-addon border-0 bg-white" id="snippet">
    <span style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-info-circle watiseenSnippetButton" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

And I have a popover:

```
<div id="SnippetTonen" class="popover right ui-content " data-shadow="false">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">
        Wat is een snippet?
        <a class="popover-close" id="closeModal">X</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <p>
            Moderne e-mailorigramma's tonen behalve het subject van de mail(het onderwerp) ook een extra
            informatieregel. Zo wordt de context van de mail sneller duidelijk als een gebruiker zijn inbox 'scant'.
            Deze tekst wordt 'snippet' genoemd en is aanpasbaar op deze pagina.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="popover-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery for showing the popover:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".watiseenSnippetButton").click(function () {
        $('#SnippetTonen').modal('show');
        $('#SnippetTonen').fadeOut('fast');
        $("#SnippetTonen").removeClass("watiseenSnippetButton");
    });
});
```

Currently the popover is shown above the icon:

[image]

How to fix this, so that the popover will be shown under the information icon?

Thank you

Comment: Did you include the opt-in JavaScript to enable the Popover component per Bootstrap's documentation?

Comment: well, it IS shown -- but it's immediately being faded out.

Comment: But it has to been visible all the time. ONly when you press the x it has to dissapear

Comment: Right. So remove the fadeOut, and make that a listener on the x's click.

Comment: can you give example? thank you

Comment: But also that the popover will be shown right next too the icon.

Comment: Might be a problem that you are actually triggering the thing as a `.modal()` but the markup is `popover`. It should be noted here as well that this is about Bootstrap 3.1.1…

Comment: yes, because if you click on it the background of the page becomes black, what not has to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the pictured UI, I think you are more into popovers than modals.

In order to fire up the popover, you could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#closeModal', function() {
        $(".watiseenSnippetButton").popover('hide');
    });

    $(".watiseenSnippetButton").popover({
        'title'     : $('#SnippetTonen .popover-title').html(),
        'content'   : $('#SnippetTonen .popover-content').html(),
        'html'      : true,
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group-addon border-0 bg-white" id="snippet">
     <span style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="popover" class="fa fa-info-circle watiseenSnippetButton" aria-hidden="true">info</span>
</div>


<div id="SnippetTonen" class="popover right ui-content " data-shadow="false">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">
        Wat is een snippet?
        <a class="popover-close" id="closeModal">X</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <p>
            Moderne e-mailorigramma's tonen behalve het subject van de mail(het onderwerp) ook een extra
            informatieregel. Zo wordt de context van de mail sneller duidelijk als een gebruiker zijn inbox 'scant'.
            Deze tekst wordt 'snippet' genoemd en is aanpasbaar op deze pagina.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="popover-footer">
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ah, very nice. Thank you. I have one question. How to set the width and height of the popover?